# Relation for maximum eigenvalue of 2-tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices, circulant-matrices

Let an 8x8 2-tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix is of the form S1. From the literature [Eigenvalues of 2-tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d0bd/9c1d891dc2ad7b68238168474fe569e52e1b.pdf) its easy to findout the maximum eigenvalue of S1.

S1=$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Is there any recurrence relation which can be formulated to find the maximum eigenvalue of variants of the two-tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix, like S2, S3 and S4 given,

S2=$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

s3=$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

s4=$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 & b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & a 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Comment: Is it in purpose that the matrices $S_2;S_3,S_4$ are $not$ general $k$-tridiagonal matrices?

Comment: Yes.. In my problem the matrix is fixed like that.. Hope I can find a relation with general k-tridiagonal matrix.